# How to make call from a class in one module to an endpoint in a Controller to a different module?

Tags: spring-boot, module, controller, endpoint, rest

I have this SpringBoot application that has two modules - **app** and **controller**. In the **controller** I have a class that do some stuff and provides endpoints for them. Now I want to call those endpoints in my **app** module in one of the classes but am not sure how. Any suggestions?

Comment: if two modules work on different ports you can make HTTP call to your controller using RestTemplate, but i'm not sure.

Comment: The problem is that this whole application will be uploaded on cloud and there I won't know which the url will be.

Comment: probably there will be ip adresses and port numbers, you can make http request with those parameters.